# VS Code: what is the keyboard short cut to clear debug console

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am not able to find in the documentation about how to clear debug console by using the keyboard shortcut.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

There is no default shortcut provided, however, you can create your own shortcut:

```
{ 
    "key": "ctrl+k",
    "command": "workbench.debug.panel.action.clearReplAction",
    "when": "inDebugRepl"
}
```

Comment: Noob here -- In what .json file do I create this? Thanks.

Comment: there's now a visual editor for keyboard shortcuts, you can find details here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

Comment: `Ctrl+k` is directly working in my visual studio code. maybe they have integrated this feature recently

Comment: Update: the feature seems to be gone now. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63369
Anyone found a workaround?

Comment: Update: the VS Code team reversed their removal of the shortcut soon after they removed it: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/ef81add15396f2f041adb263027492ef69e9950d

Answer (score 16):

[image: file->preferences->keyboard shortcuts]

[image: search "clear console" or "clear Output"(if) then press enter .Just Add your keyboard Combination,like Win key or other key]

file->preferences->keyboard shortcuts.
Search "clear console" or "clear Output"(if) then press enter .Just Add your keyboard Combination,like Win key or other key

Answer (score 13):

[image]

Click on that button (top and right of the console window) highlighted in the red color.

Answer (score 8):

Just using the clear console icon that is at top and right of the console window.

Comment: If you aren't needing a "keyboard shortcut" then simply right-mouse click in the console output window and select "Clear Console"

Answer (score 5):

Open `keybindings.json` (you can also just hit `cmd+shift+p` and then type `Open Keyboard Shortcuts`) and add this:

```
{
    "key": "cmd+k",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.clear",
    "when": "terminalFocus"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to configure settings.
<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> is the shortcut.

Comment: Consider adding some source to back the affirmation "setting are just wrong and useless". From the other answers and comments it looks like `ctrl+k` has been added as a default shortcut **after** this question was answered. If that is the case, An explanation of that with maybe some link to the docs would be awesome. An statement of 1 line like this is more of a comment than an answer (RealSteel actually commented that in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

  In my case I define the "workbench.action.terminal.clear" to
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
  +
  <kbd>K</kbd>
  shortcut in the Keyboard Shortcuts Setting.

  And I use for the first time the
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
  +
  <kbd>K</kbd>
  shortcut
  then I use only the
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
  +
  <kbd>L</kbd>
  shortcut.

  Because when I use only
  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
  +
  <kbd>K</kbd>
  changing the console height causes the return of the console content.